# Identifying gdld cookie in Wordpress Site

Tags: wordpress, cookies

Using "GDPR Cookie Consent" plugin (Premium) and it has a nifty cookie scanner, where it logs all cookies my site uses.  Sadly under the description in all of them, it auto-populates as "description unavailable".  So one by one (I only have 17) I'm gathering data on each to add proper descriptions.  There is one in particular I'm having a hard time finding ANY info on:

Cookie Name: gdld
Type: Persistent
Category: Non Necessary
Duration: 9 years
Sensitivity: non-necessary
ID: gdld

Does anyone have any idea what this could be so I can be 100% sure I'm GDPR compliant? Thanks in advance :)